# Writing data to Firebase, Android

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have an App which uses Firebase and it uses 'push' to write a record. My problem is with updating the content of that record. Any help very welcome. I am using `Firebase Authentication` email/password and that works fine. I also have my database in a Java Class which also works fine. In `onCreate` method I have the data referenced:

```
 databasePropertyData FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("users");
```

Using a button I can create a new record with it's unique identifier, which is what I want:

```
    String ownerId = databasePropertyData.push().getKey();
    PropertyData propertyData = new PropertyData(ownerId, ownerName, name);
    databasePropertyData.child(ownerId).setValue(propertyData);
```

This code works fine and creates a record with the user id just as I want.

However, I now want to update that particular record and that is where the problems lies. The code I have used (and a myriad variations) sets up a new record rather than updating the existing data. This is one example of my failed experimentation:

```
   String ownerId = databasePropertyData.getKey();
   databasePropertyData.child(ownerId).setValue(name,ownerName);
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: can you show the node pitcure?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is happening because you are using the `push()` method. It generates a new random key every time you are signing in. To solve this, use the `uid` instead of the pushed key.

```
PropertyData propertyData = new PropertyData(ownerId, ownerName, name);
String uid = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid();
databasePropertyData.child(uid).setValue(propertyData);
```

The benefit of using the `uid` is that you can update the record very easily.

```
databasePropertyData.child(uid).updateChildren(propertyData);
```

Comment: Thanks for responding. On the App the user can set up an account with Authentication and then a link to a data input page. The save button on that page either runs an option which runs code using  'push' - for a new user. Or it runs code for an existing user. The new user code works fine, the existing user code does not.

I tried your example but was unable to make it work - I do the getCurrentUser and put it into a string etc. Using the updateChildren(name, ownerName) I get an error with the (owner, ownerName) part - "Completion listener in database reference cannot be applied". Any ideas?

Comment: I just copied your code and didn't see the arguments. The correct argument is the `propertyData` object. Please see my updated answer. It will work for sure. Can you confirm that?

Comment: Hey. After some tweaking it is now writing and updating records as it is supposed to. Thank you so much for taking the trouble to help out. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can update specified field using updateChild, here is ref:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/read-and-write#update_specific_fields

Comment: That is a link to the Google reference page, which I have looked at already. However, that link is to the web ref and not Android!!

Answer (score 0):

```
String ownerId = databasePropertyData.getKey();
```

here instead of creating new `ownerId`, you should use the same Id of the propertyData that you want to update. Then using `updateChildren` or `setValue` method, you can update the value.
Then this will work fine:

```
databasePropertyData = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("users");
PropertyData propertyData = new PropertyData(ownerId, ownerName, name);
databasePropertyData.child(ownerId).setValue(propertyData);
```

Comment: I did use .getCurrentUser(). So the user has logged into an Authenticated account already set up and where data has been saved. What I am struggling with is how to overwrite the existing data. I cannot seem to get it to work even when I use getCurrentUser which I thought would give access to the existing data.

Comment: Srushti, there is no `setValue()` method with two arguments. setValue() method is not a constructor. You need to pass the `propertyData` object as an argument, not the actual values.

Comment: @AlexMamo sorry for that. I have updated in the answer. The firebase will update only those values that you set in your object. So if you want to update only name, then set name in the object and then pass that object in setValue method.

Answer (score 0):

You have this in your database:

```
 users
   randomid
       ownerId: 12345
       ownerName: userx
       name: anothername
```

To update you can do this, since you are using `push()`, then use the variable that has the key in it and do this:

```
String ownerId = databasePropertyData.push().getKey(); //the variable that has the key, not a new variable
PropertyData propertyData = new PropertyData(ownerId, ownerName, name);
databasePropertyData.child(ownerId).setValue(propertyData);
```

Or instead of this, you can change the database structure and use user id:

```
     FirebaseUser user=FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
     PropertyData propertyData = new PropertyData(ownerId, ownerName, name);
    databasePropertyData.child(ownerId).setValue(propertyData);
```

Or you can make a query and retrieve the `push()` key from the database and update the values in the query.

But you have to update all 3 fields.